# MYSQL check if a chain of dates exists

Tags: mysql

I want to check in MySQL if a chain of dates exists longer than 5. For example:

```
11-05-2016  
12-05-2016  
13-05-2016  
14-05-2016  
15-05-2016
```

These would be rows in my DB, this would be a chain of 5. I want to make a trigger on my table to protect my data from making chains bigger than 5.

Comment: Your problem is in your approach. MySQL relies on a relational model. Those dates should be in separate rows linked to another table via foreign keys. Then, you can ask yourself about the constrains you add to your schema.

Comment: What if the 16th and 17th are present but the 13th is missing?  Could you insert '13'?

Comment: @HéctorValverdePareja Care to elaborate?

Comment: No then '13 would not be a valid insert because that would form a chain of 7 dates. @Strawberry

Comment: @HéctorValverdePareja Not sure what you mean by this, how is foreign keys related to my question? edit: Maybe I wasn't clear about the dates being in serparate rows, those five dates in the original post would be five serparate rows.

Comment: @SuperNewb, I'd love to, but I'm afraid I'm not an expert. But bear in mind you're probably facing a problem which is caused by a bad approach. It's your decision to do a workaround or give a step back and select a different approach.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an incomplete answer...

I ain't pretending this is pretty (and it scales poorly too), but this does at least demonstrate a principle that others might build off...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table(dt DATE NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
('2016-05-01'),
('2016-05-02'),
('2016-05-03'),
('2016-05-05'),
('2016-05-07'),
('2016-05-08'),
('2016-05-09'),
('2016-05-11'),
('2016-05-12'),
('2016-05-13'),
('2016-05-14');
```

Here we have a streak of 3 days (1st to 3rd), followed by a streak of 1 day  (5th), followed by another streak of 3 days (7th to 9th), followed by a 4 day streak (11th to 14th).

So, we should be able to insert a value of '2016-05-15' (because that would produce a 5-day streak), but not '2016-05-10' (because that would make an 8-day streak).

1. 2016-05-10

```
SET @x = '2016-05-10';

SELECT  a.dt start
     ,  MIN(c.dt) end 
  FROM 
     ( SELECT dt FROM my_table 
       UNION
       SELECT @x
     ) a
  LEFT 
  JOIN
     ( SELECT dt FROM my_table 
       UNION
       SELECT @x
     ) b
    ON b.dt = a.dt - INTERVAL 1 DAY
  LEFT 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT dt FROM my_table
       UNION
       SELECT @x
     ) c
    ON c.dt >= a.dt
  LEFT 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT dt FROM my_table       
       UNION
       SELECT @x
     ) d
    ON d.dt = c.dt + INTERVAL 1 DAY
 WHERE b.dt IS NULL 
   AND c.dt IS NOT NULL
   AND d.dt IS NULL
 GROUP  
    BY a.dt
HAVING DATEDIFF(end,start)>5;

+------------+------------+
| start      | end        |
+------------+------------+
| 2016-05-07 | 2016-05-15 |
+------------+------------+
```

2. 2016-05-15

```
SET @x = '2016-05-15';

SELECT  a.dt start
     ,  MIN(c.dt) end 
  FROM 
     ( SELECT dt FROM my_table 
       UNION
       SELECT @x
     ) a
  LEFT 
  JOIN
     ( SELECT dt FROM my_table 
       UNION
       SELECT @x
     ) b
    ON b.dt = a.dt - INTERVAL 1 DAY
  LEFT 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT dt FROM my_table
       UNION
       SELECT @x
     ) c
    ON c.dt >= a.dt
  LEFT 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT dt FROM my_table       
       UNION
       SELECT @x
     ) d
    ON d.dt = c.dt + INTERVAL 1 DAY
 WHERE b.dt IS NULL 
   AND c.dt IS NOT NULL
   AND d.dt IS NULL
 GROUP  
    BY a.dt
HAVING DATEDIFF(end,start)>5;

Empty set (0.03 sec)
```